# Should I remove or add pixels and then scale up?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, photo-editing

I would like to make this image to have 4:3 ratio, so it then later can be scaled up so it completely fits a 400mm x 300mm paper when printed.

[image]

It can not be cropped any more, so the size is 780x500, which is not 4:3.

**Question**

As it needs to be scaled up when printed

- should I scale it down horizontally so I get 667*500 (remove pixels)

or

- should I scale it up vertically so I get 585*500 (add pixels)

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you will be able to scale a 780 x 500 to 400mm x 300mm... I would recommend scaling it up though to preserve pixels as when you scale down you are losing pixels. But I just want to tell you that 400mm x 300mm is 4724 x 3543 pixels, so no matter what you do, enlarging it that much will make it look low quality.

Comment: Sandra didn't say it has to be 400x300 mm. Just 4:3 ratio.

Comment: Yes she did " so it then later can be scaled up so it completely fits a 400mm x 300mm paper when printed"

Comment: Printed on 400x300mm **paper** which is not the same. That's not 4724 x 3543 pixels.

Comment: She said she wants it to completely fit the paper. At 300 DPI that is indeed 4724 x 3543

Comment: DPI has no effect on the printing size, just how sharp an image looks. DPI does after all stand for 'dots per inch'.

Comment: Exactly, and if you want an image to look good when you print it, it should be at at least 300 DPI. It doens't affect printing size, but if she used like 72, then it would look worse.

Comment: That's completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I guess its technically not, but you always want to think about quality when resizing :)

Answer (score 1):

Decide for yourself:
667x500 (horizontally scaled down)
[image: 667x500]

780x629 (vertically scaled up)
[image: 780x629]

Make sure you watch the images at 100%, so just right-click 'view image' or download them.

BTW the '585x500' pixels you mentioned is a bit of a wrong calculation ;)

Sidenote: this is a good image for scaling in one dimension, but most images will look very ugly and distorted when you perform this action. Beware :)